# Java Connection String to Oracle Cloud Database

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I had problem when connecting to Oracle Cloud Database from java code.

- I have no problem connecting other non-cloud oracle databases.
- I can connect to the Oracle Cloud Database with sql tools, except from the java codes.
- The hostname, username and password is correct one, i don't reveal the real username and password.

Error: java.sql.SQLException:

```
SQLException: SQLState(null) vendor code(17002)
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm
```

My code as following:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.133.133.23:1521:ORCL";

try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "username1", "password");


}catch(Exception)
{
  e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Comment: "ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm"  http://psoug.org/oraerror/ORA-12650.htm

Comment: yup, i will re-edit the post with this message

Comment: Try this [post from Oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1325615?start=0&tstart=0) which might help.. It seems you have to setup your SQLNET.ORA appropriately for JDBC thin client which it seems is what you are using

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * The below one is for oracle thin client
   Its worked for the ojdbc6 driver. 
 */
public Connection conCheck() {

      Connection con=null;
      try { //step1 load the driver class
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", "REQUIRED");
      props.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client",  "( " + AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES256 + "," +AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES192 + ")");
      props.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client", "( SHA1 )");
      props.put("user", "username");
      props.put("password","password");

    //step2 create  the connection object          
      con=DriverManager.getConnection(  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:serveiceid",props);

       System.out.println("Con"+con);
      }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }       

 return con;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like changing syntax in your connection string to lookup `SERVICE_NAME` instead of `SID` must help you connect your database.

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.133.133.23:1521/ORCL";
```

> Additional Read : [Thin-style Service Name Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA)

If this as well doesn't help, then would suggest to add below 2 lines to your sqlnet.ora in database.

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT= (SHA1)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT = requested
```

Answer (score 0):

First mandatory check is to verify the oracle jdbc version. if you use  incompatible version,we will get this kid of errors.